# How to save css info after a full page refresh

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to keep a white underline under each nav bar menu item when it's selected but when I click on each menu item in the navbar I do a full page refresh because I'm directing the user to a new controller/action/view. How can I persist the css so that even after I redirect to a new controller with a new view I still have the menu item underlined that was clicked? Note - the view rerenders the navbar menu, which is contained in a partial view

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".nav-pills a").click(function() {
    $(".nav-pills a").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    //$(this).css("color", "black");
  });
});
```

```css
   .menupartial {
     background-color: #16749F;
     /*opacity: .9;*/
     /*width: 100%;*/
     margin-bottom: 20px;
   }
   .menupartial a {
     color: lightgrey;
     font-weight: bold;
   }
   .nav-pills > li > a {
     border-radius: 0;
   }
   .nav-pills > li > a:hover {
     border-radius: 0;
     background-color: #16749F;
     color: white;
   }
   .nav-pills > li > a:active,
   .nav-pills > li > a.active {
     border-bottom: 5px solid white;
   }
   /*div.container.body-content {
           background-color: yellow;
            
        }*/
```

```html
<div class="row menupartial">
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
      <li>@Html.ActionLink("User", "UserProfile", "Account")</li>
      <li>@Html.ActionLink("Profiles", "Index", "Profile")</li>
      <li>@Html.ActionLink("YogaSpaces", "Index", "YogaSpace")</li>
      <li><a href="#">Your Schedules</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Your Messages</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Your Groups</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Your Friends</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not do this on the server side where you assign the class `"active"` to the current page... If this is not an option you can try the old trick of adding a unique `id` to the `body` tag and then in the CSS add rules to activate a certain menu item depending on the id of body...

Comment: can you provide me with any examples?

Comment: See this for dynamic server-side highlighting - http://dbwebb.se/kod-exempel/dynamic_php_menu/ 
As for the other method, it's something like `body#home li.home { border-bottom: 5px solid white; }` and so on...

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="@(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"].ToString() == "User" ? "active" : "")">@Html.ActionLink("User", "UserProfile", "Account")</li>
    <li class="@(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"].ToString() == "Profiles" ? "active" : "")">@Html.ActionLink("Profiles", "Index", "Profile")</li>
    <li class="@(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"].ToString() == "YogaSpaces" ? "active" : "")">@Html.ActionLink("YogaSpaces", "Index", "YogaSpace")</li>
</ul>
```

Using bootstrap classes here.

Comment: So here I am using Action name and deciding which of the menu will have active class. If you need to modify your css, please do. I have not looked at your css because its late night here and I am feeling sleepy :)